# UPDATE table1, then insert ids into another table2

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to update MemberTable and then take those memberIds into another table.Each time I update member table,I am expecting to update multiple records.I need to capture each of the updated memberIds of the updated members and insert into another table.Any suggestions to do this correctly

Here is what I have tried so far.

```
Declare @memberId int;
  BEGIN TRANSACTION;

BEGIN TRY
   UPDATE [AC]
   SET [AC].LoginName = [ME].Email,@memberId=[ME].MemberId
   FROM Account AS [AC]
   INNER JOIN Member AS [ME] ON [ME].AccountId=[AC].AccountID
   WHERE  year([AC].SignupDate)=2015 AND [AC].LoginName IS NULL 

   --OUTPUT [ME].MemberId INTO 

   INSERT INTO .[dbo].[Tracktable] 
           ([MemberId]
           ,[CompanyId]
           ,[Action]
           ,[DateModified]
           ,[DateProcessed])
     VALUES
           (@memberId,
           null,  
           1,
           GETDATE(),
          null

          )
   END TRY
 BEGIN CATCH
 IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
 END CATCH
 IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;

    GO
```

Comment: You could use a trigger after UPDATE.

Comment: What problems are you having with an `OUTPUT` clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First store the MemberId into the temporary table and the same detail can insert into Tracktable. It can capture each of the updated MemberIds of the updated members and insert into Tracktable.

Added inline comments.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

BEGIN TRY

    -- Storing the MemberId into temporary table,
    -- to store the detail in Tracktable
    SELECT [ME].MemberId INTO #TempForTracking
    FROM Account AS [AC]
    INNER JOIN Member AS [ME] ON [ME].AccountId = [AC].AccountID
    WHERE  year([AC].SignupDate) = 2015 AND [AC].LoginName IS NULL      

    UPDATE [AC]
    SET [AC].LoginName = [ME].Email
    FROM Account AS [AC]
    INNER JOIN Member AS [ME] ON [ME].AccountId = [AC].AccountID
    WHERE  year([AC].SignupDate) = 2015 AND [AC].LoginName IS NULL 

    -- Inserting the MemberId from temp table
    -- into the Tracktable
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Tracktable] 
           ([MemberId], [CompanyId], [Action], [DateModified], [DateProcessed])
    SELECT MemberId, NULL, 1, GETDATE(), NULL
    FROM #TempForTracking

    DROP TABLE #TempForTracking

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

END CATCH

IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;

GO
```